# Converting a list to json in python

Tags: python, json, list

Here is the code, I have a list, which I want to convert to JSON with dynamic keys.

```
>>> print (list) #list
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

>>> outfile = open('c:\\users\\fawads\desktop\csd\\Test44.json','w')#writing data to file
>>> for entry in list:
...    data={'key'+str(i):entry}
...    i+=1
...    json.dump(data,outfile)
...
>>> outfile.close()
```

The result is as following:

```
{"key0": "a"}{"key1": "b"}{"key2": "c"}{"key3": "d"}
```

Which is not valid json.

Comment: `json_data = [] ... json_data.append(data) ... json.dump(json_data, outfile)` if you want a list in json data then make a list in json data!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I followed your method and I got the result like this [{"key0": "a"}][{"key0": "a"}, {"key1": "b"}][{"key0": "a"}, {"key1": "b"}, {"key2": "c"}][{"key0": "a"}, {"key1": "b"}, {"key2": "c"}, {"key3": "d"}]

Comment: could you show what you want the correct output to be?

Answer (score 1):

```
 data = []
 for entry in lst:
    data.append({'key'+str(lst.index(entry)):entry})

 json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate your list (which you should not call `list`, by the way, you will shadow the built in list):

```
>>> import json
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> jso = {'key{}'.format(k):v for k, v in enumerate(lst)}
>>> json.dumps(jso)
'{"key3": "d", "key2": "c", "key1": "b", "key0": "a"}'
```

Comment: OP's format it not valid JSON, this is my suggestion for valid JSON.

Comment: I was under the impression the op wanted something like `[{'key0': 'a'}, {'key1': 'b'}, {'key2': 'c'}, {'key3': 'd'}]` but now realize that it may not the desired behaviour...

Comment: Thanks @timgeb. Why are the values in reverse order? How they can be according to the order as in lst?

Comment: @Fawad dictionaries and the JSON format don't have a concept of order. It's just coincidence that the keys appear reversed.

Answer (score 1):

As a minimal change which I originally posted in a comment:

```
outfile = open('c:\\users\\fawads\desktop\csd\\Test44.json','w')#writing data to file
all_data = [] #keep a list of all the entries
i = 0
for entry in list:
    data={'key'+str(i):entry}
    i+=1
    all_data.append(data) #add the data to the list

json.dump(all_data,outfile) #write the list to the file

outfile.close()
```

calling `json.dump` on the same file multiple times is very rarely useful as it creates multiple segments of json data that needs to be seperated in order to be parsed, it makes much more sense to only call it **once** when you are done constructing the data.

I'd also like to suggest you use `enumerate` to handle the `i` variable as well as using a `with` statement to deal wit the file IO:

```
all_data = [] #keep a list of all the entries
for i,entry in enumerate(list):
    data={'key'+str(i):entry}
    all_data.append(data)

with open('c:\\users\\fawads\desktop\csd\\Test44.json','w') as outfile:
    json.dump(all_data,outfile)
#file is automatically closed at the end of the with block (even if there is an e
```

The loop could be shorted even further with list comprehension:

```
all_data = [{'key'+str(i):entry}
            for i,entry in enumerate(list)]
```

Which (if you really want) could be put directly into the `json.dump`:

```
with open('c:\\users\\fawads\desktop\csd\\Test44.json','w') as outfile:
    json.dump([{'key'+str(i):entry}
                for i,entry in enumerate(list)],
              outfile)
```

although then you start to lose readability so I don't recommend going that far.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helps a lot as a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do:

```
mydict = {}
i = 0
for entry in list:
  dict_key = "key" + str(i)
  mydict[dict_key] = entry
  i = i + 1
json.dump(mydict, outfile)
```

Currently you are creating a new dict entry in every iteration of the loop , hence the result is not a valid json.